# Mysql : Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mysql-workbench

I was doing indexing in Mysql to speed up the search in the database. I indexed 2-3 columns in each of 5-6 tables. Later, when I added 2 column indexes in another table and "Apply changes", I got the error "Lost connection to MySQL server during query". After this error, I can no longer even select that table, the same error appears. The selection of other tables works normally, only this error occurs in this table.

Even after trying several times Mysql server started crashing and every time after booting it crashes again. Do you know why the error occurred or how to solve it? Will it be fixed if I delete the indexes I added to other tables?